# cache table should be truncated if doing it in database?

Tags: 7, database, caching

Given this information from [Clearing cache](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache)

> In the database 
>   Use phpMyAdmin or another tool to access the database tables and TRUNCATE (empty, not remove) all tables that start with cache_.

Should I also truncate the table called cache as is?

Comment: Yes, by truncating all the tables starting with cache you can clear your cached data

Comment: But there is a table called just "cache" i should truncate it as well, right?

Comment: Yes you should.